# Удаление знаков в строке

Tags: python, строки, текст

Как убрать запятые? Если я ввожу в текст "money" без запятой, программа считает, что это другое слово.

```
b = {}

def return_amount(phrase):
    a = phrase.lower().split(" ")
    for word in a:
        b[word] = a.count(word)



return_amount("Money, money, money, it’s always sunny, in the richmen’s world")
print(b)
```

Comment: Типичный пример проблемы XY. Вы спрашиваете как убрать запятые, хотя настоящая задача заключается в том как подсчитать количество слов в строке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы также можете воспользоваться `Counter` из библиотеки `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter

def return_amount(phrase):
    return Counter(phrase.lower().replace(",", "").split())
```

Comment: Этот код годится только для запятых. Что если в тексте будут ещё точки и прочие знаки?

Comment: Это верно, поэтому правильным ответом выбран вариант с регулярным выражением.

Answer (score 8):

Вариант с удалением запятой, безусловно, будет работать для приведенного Вами примера текста, но совершенно не подойдет для текста, состояшего из нескольких предложений, да еще и со сложной пунктуацией в виде точек, двоеточий, точек с запятой, тире и т.д.. Посему предложу свой вариант. Если хотите, оберните его в функцию. Но, ИМХО, его можно использовать и так, поскольку код однострочный:

```
from re import findall
from collections import Counter

text = "Money, money, money, it’s always sunny, in the richmen’s world."
print(Counter(findall('\S*\w', text.lower())))
# Counter({'money': 3, 'it’s': 1, 'always': 1, 'sunny': 1, 'in': 1, 'the': 1, 'richmen’s': 1, 'world': 1})
```

Коротко о ключах использованных в регулярном выражении:

> `\S` - любой не пробельный символ
>   `\w` - любая буква, любая цифра или знак `_` (нижнее подчеркивание)
>   `*` - означает, что указанный перед ним шаблон, должен встретиться 0 или более раз подряд

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы удалить символы из строки можно воспользоваться методом `replace`:

```
a = phrase.replace(",", "")
```

Полный код функции:

```
def return_amount(phrase):
    a = phrase.replace(",", "")
    a = a.lower().split(" ")
    for word in a:
        b[word] = a.count(word)
```

Comment: шик. Работает) Спасибо)

Comment: Этот код годится только для запятых. Что если в тексте будут ещё точки и прочие знаки?

Comment: Изначальный вопрос был только про запятые. Если говорить про удаление прочих знаков, то предложенный вариант с регулярками безусловно лучше.